# XPath '//div/following-sibling::div' select nothing?

Tags: xpath

there is a xml, http://kquery.veryos.com/w3.xml

open chrome developer tool, and run 'document.querySelectorAll("div ~ div")' in console, returns 4292 elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div ~ div')
NodeList[4292]
```

but using the XPath experssion equals to css selector 'div ~ div', select nothing, no element returns.

```
result = document.evaluate('//div/following-sibling::div',document,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE);
result.iterateNext(); //null

result = document.evaluate('//div[preceding-sibling::div]',document,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE);
result.iterateNext(); //null

r=document.evaluate('//div/following-sibling::*', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
r.iterateNext(); //element
```

any problems of the experssion '//div/following-sibling::div' or '//div[preceding-sibling::div]' ?

anybody helps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `div` in the document. Therefore, searching for a `div` preceded by another `div` returns nothing.

Comment: thanks, this xml is converted from a html, I suppose it maybe contains many divs, so not check its content.